# AWS Instance unreachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and trying to launch an EC2 instance, which indeed was successful, but now when i am trying to ping the public IP, it's unreachable.

P.S: I have already opened the inbound ports 80, 22 and 443 for ssh, http and https respectively, but still can't even ping the public IP.

Thanks,

Biraj

Comment: Ping needs ICMP port open.

Comment: Hi Kosa, ICMP is also enabled for all ports (0-65535 ). Moreover I can't even do a ssh ec2-user@public_ip .

Comment: are you running your instance in the default vpc provided in your account?

Comment: Troubleshooting connectivity: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Comment: Hi Daniel, Yes i am using default VPC, i choose the default option while lauching EC2 instance. Anyways the issue is fixed now, what i feel is after enabling ICMP its takes some time before you can start pinging AWS public IP Address. Thank you all for your help :)